# How to restart a SpeechRecognition function in Framer?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, framerjs

I want to build a function in Framer (coffeescript) where I can say a specific word as voice input and something happens. For example I say "apple" then a rectangle turns green. If I say "banana" it turns yellow.

So far it works only once and then I have to refresh the prototype in order to record a new word. How can I make it fluent, so I can say more words and always change the colors?

Here is my current code. I use the Google Chrome API for speech recognition, so the prototype itself only works if you open it in the Chrome Browser.

```
SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition or 
window.webkitSpeechRecognition
recognizer = new SpeechRecognition
recognizer.lang = 'de-DE'

recognizer.continuous = true
recognizer.interimResults = true

recognizer.start()

recognizer.onresult = (event) ->
  result = event.results[event.resultIndex]
  if result[0].transcript is "Apfel"
    rect.backgroundColor = "green"
  else if result[0].transcript is "Banane"
    rect.backgroundColor = "yellow"
  return
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the prefixed properties `webkitSpeechRecognition()` and `webkitSpeechGrammarList()`. Was only able to get the engine to recognize `"red"` as input grammar, though the `result` event is fired more than once.

```js
var grammar = '#JSGF V1.0; grammar colors; public <color> = aqua | azure | beige | bisque | black | blue | brown | chocolate | coral | crimson | cyan | fuchsia | ghostwhite | gold | goldenrod | gray | green | indigo | ivory | khaki | lavender | lime | linen | magenta | maroon | moccasin | navy | olive | orange | orchid | peru | pink | plum | purple | red | salmon | sienna | silver | snow | tan | teal | thistle | tomato | turquoise | violet | white | yellow ;'
var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
var speechRecognitionList = new webkitSpeechGrammarList();
speechRecognitionList.addFromString(grammar, 1);
recognition.grammars = speechRecognitionList;
recognition.continuous = true;
recognition.lang = 'en-US';
recognition.interimResults = true;
recognition.maxAlternatives = 0;

var diagnostic = document.querySelector('.output');
var bg = document.querySelector('html');

document.body.onclick = function() {
  recognition.start();
  console.log('Ready to receive a color command.');
}

recognition.onresult = function(event) {
  console.log(event);
  var color = event.results[0][0].transcript;
  diagnostic.textContent = 'Result received: ' + color;
  bg.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```html
<body>
click
<div class="output">
```